# Remove characters from right side until a special character is reached

Tags: ruby, string

I have a variable that represents a path:

```
path = "/foo/bar"
```

I want to remove the last part of the path. I tried it with `gsub!` like this:

```
path.gsub!("/bar","")
```

but I also want to throw an error if `"/bar"` isn't at the end of the string. I also tried `path.split("/")`, but this seems not very memory efficient. The method is called a lot, so an in-place approach would be perfect. Another variation would be to only remove every string until `"/"` is hit, without throwing the error.

What would be a fast and memory efficient method to do this?

Comment: Ruby is moving towards immutable strings. An "inplace approach" could mean future trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a Regexp to match only at the end of the string:

```
'/foo/bar'.gsub!(/\/bar\z/, '')
#=> '/foo'
```

Since `gsub!` returns `nil` if there wasn't a match, just combine it with raising an error:

```
'/foo/blub'.gsub!(/\/bar\z/, '') || raise(StandardError)
#=> StandardError: StandardError
```

Answer (score 2):

To get what you want, you can do:

```
File.dirname("/foo/bar")
# => "/foo"
```

To raise an error is a different thing:

```
raise unless "/foo/bar".end_with?("/bar")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `String#rindex` to find the last occurrence of `/` and use that value to get the preceding sub-string:

```
path[0, path.rindex("/")]
```